# Webdriver testing and google OAuth

Tags: webdriver, automated-tests, google-oauth, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I have an e2e test for a rather large application. It offers multiple ways of authenticating an user, one of which is using a google account by aquiring a OAuth2 token. Today it runs naively by manipulating the logon page that pops up and enters the logon details.

As expected, at some point google decided to throw this in my face:
[image]

How can I skip the manual logon procedure, grab an Oauth token and procede to my redirect url, and verify that I indeed arrive at the correct place in my application with selenium?

[Offline authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) seems to be what I am looking for, however webdriver cannot do POST requests. I am able to acquire the token manually, but there's no way to pass it on to webdriver in any meaningful way as it still can't do anything with it.

If possible I would prefer to not touch the application codebase.

I am using `webdriverio` as my webdriver implementation, running as a `nodejs` task. Interestingly the robot filter appears rarely on my local machine, but seems to always trigger on the `circleci` instance it's run on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply using my app endpoint to get a token from google, then using the JavaScript executor I set the token in the local storage.

Something like this.

```
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem('token', ' " + apiRequest.getToken() + "');");
```

I hope this is what are you looking for.